# RSACryptoServiceProvider - Decrypt

Tags: c#, criptografia, rsa

Usando a criptografia RSA, eu passo os dados encriptados do *client* para o *server* decriptar. Ao tentar decriptar, ele me devolve uma exceção `CryptographicException` com a mensagem:

> Sinalizadores inválidos especificados.

Não tenho ideia de que Flag possa estar faltando.

Meu código se encontra da seguinte maneira:

```
byte[] decryptedMessage;
RSACryptoServiceProvider asr = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(128);
decryptedMessage = asr.Decrypt(buffer, false);
```

> em System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptogaphicException(Int32 hr)
>          em System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._GenerateKey(SafeProvHandle hProv, Int32 algid, CspProviderFlags flags, Int32 keySize, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
>          em System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
>          em System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
>          em System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` não dá suporte a chaves de 128 bits:

> Os tamanhos de chave de suporte de [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) de 384 bits a 16384 bits em incrementos de 8 bits se você tiver o provedor de criptografia aprimorado Microsoft instalado. Suporta tamanhos de chave de 384 bits a 512 bits em incrementos de 8 bits se você tiver o Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider instalado.

Fonte: [MSDN - Propriedade `RSACryptoServiceProvider.KeySize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.keysize.aspx)

[Resposta original no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13988424/520779).

Comment: Essa parte tudo bem, já tinha lido sobre em outros lugares, mas qual a solução que tenho então para decryptar o dado ??

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi Seria possível modificar o client para usar um tamanho de chave maior? 128 bits para o RSA é terrivelmente inseguro... Caso contrário, imagino que será necessário buscar uma implementação alternativa, ou talvez delegar a tarefa a um sistema externo (tipo o openssl).

Comment: eu estou utilizando openssl, e mandando dados encryptados utilizando RSA para o servidor a partir de uma SSLStream